# Convert select max case to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How do I convert this select query to laravel query builder?

```
select
wi.id,
wi.nama,
max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '2k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as country,
max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '3k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as gender,
max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '4k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as purpose,
group_concat(distinct wo.id_objek) as visit_to
```

Initial

```
wi => ta_wisatawan
dw => ta_k_detail_wisatawan
ks => ta_kriteria_sub
wo => ta_k_wisata_objek
```

Convert in this query builder

```
$show_wi = DB::table('ta_wisatawan')
->leftJoin('ta_k_detail_wisatawan', 'ta_k_detail_wisatawan.id_wisatawan', '=', 'ta_wisatawan.id')
->leftJoin('ta_kriteria_sub', 'ta_kriteria_sub.kode', '=', 'ta_k_detail_wisatawan.kode_kriteria')
->leftJoin('ta_k_wisata_objek', 'ta_k_wisata_objek.id_wisatawan', '=', 'ta_wisatawan.id')
->select(.....)
```

I've done several ways to this select, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::raw` accepts a string so try the following query:

```
->select(
    DB::raw(
        "wi.id, wi.nama, max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '2k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as country, max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '3k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as gender, max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '4k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as purpose"
    )
)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the use of `DB::raw()` to work with querybuilder like this:

```
->select(DB::raw([
    "wi.id",
    "wi.nama",
    "max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '2k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as country",
    "max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '3k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as gender",
    "max(case when dw.kode_kriteria like '4k%' then ks.nama_kriteria_sub else '' end) as purpose",
]))->get();
```

> See more about [Laravel's Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've try, and find this error "Array to string conversion"